# How do I correctly use select2 Jquery to search and select data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-select2

Hi All I have been trying to apply this Select2 jQuery plugin for sometime now but it doesn't work. I followed the demo example given but it always shows an error like this. The html select option have null data.

project.html

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label">Customer Name</label>
       <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
           <select required class="form-control customer-options" name="ptype" ng-model="projDetails.cname">
               <option ng-repeat="cusName in cusNames" value="{{cusName.Id}}">{{cusName.Name}}</option>
           </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery implementation.
project.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".customer-options").select2();
        });

        $scope.createProject = function () {
            var projDetails = {

                pname: $scope.projDetails.pname,
                cname:$scope.projDetails.cname,
                ptype: $scope.projDetails.ptype,
                desc: $scope.projDetails.desc,
                std: $scope.projDetails.std,
                etd: $scope.projDetails.etd,
                status:"Not assinged"
            };

            ProjService.Project(projDetails, function (res) {

                console.log(res, data);



            });
```

I gave last couple of codes so that anyone can understand that I bind data. :)

The error is this :=

> angular.js:13642 query function not defined for Select2 s2id_cname

How to make this correctly work. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: angularjs and jquery plugins don't play nice with each other. you should consider wrapping the plugin inside an Angular directive instead.

Comment: You also have a select2 directive that you can use as is in an angular application https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it works for me. You can convert it to anularjs or use as it is.
http://ionicmobile.blogspot.in/2015/10/jquery-select2-editable-with-dynamic.html